# conditional interface keys based on generic

Tags: typescript

I want to accomplish that certain keys in my interface are only valid if a specific generic that can have specific values is set.

Something like

```
type DeviceType = "A" | "B" | "default"

interface IIconSet<DEVICE extends DeviceType> {
    info: string;
    download: DEVICE extends "A" ? string : never;
    refresh: DEVICE extends ("A" | "B") ? string : never;
}
```

However if i use it like this TypeScript apparently can't properly infer what keys should be present in the interface since with the following Object

```
export const icons: IIconSet<"default"> {
    info: "svgString"
}
```

i get the error: `Type is missing the following properties from type IIconSet<"default">: download, refresh`. The same occurs when specifying `IIconSet<"B">` (in this case i get the error that `download` is missing, as soon as i add the `refresh` key).

However when defining the object with interface `IIconSet<"A">` it works just fine.

I tried to tinker around with making said fields optional but then, when i want to get that iconset out of a factory e.g. with typecasting to `IIconSet<"A">` i get an error, that `download` could potentially undefined.

What would be the proper solution to accomplish this -> excluding keys when the generic passed doesn't fit to the constraints?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBuBLAxhAKuaBeKByAgrlAD54BCRpuAJhAGYCGArgDbC4DcAUF6JLAhTpMAWQZgoOAN5coUfAC4oMuXOoB7AO4A7FuobUlAZ2AAnRNoDm3VVFP17RgBbGzF67KgBfG1DJKVVXs6RxcoE3MrXx8uGN5MKABJROR1bQBlCGAAHjQoCAAPYAhtaiMBJFQMfhw4SuFIAD5JKDzC4tLytE8AfmUoCzp1V0jLbygAMigACjaikrKoAGsIEHU6CqFqiDEJPrqt0XEAbTQAXSgArwBKTyVtBAhTbi5CsHVTYChU7RMBn6MSmSP0yORo9GYbFwzWknkGwzwRnglnSbisuAANLEXm8Pl8AV8UGkjIokik0qDsgRoS1AvClLh4ZjPBodHoDAzmXJgqEGQxmTEgA) work for you? If yes I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: i guess... this works out yes. Fiddled around in my project with it.
Thank you! a detailed explanation would be welcomed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need are [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions). We will create a separate type to hold every `DeviceType`:

```
type DeviceType = 'A' | 'B' | 'default';
```

Now let's create a type that will hold the unique parts for every `DeviceType`:

```
type DeviceTypeMap = {
  A: {
    download: string;
    refresh: string;
  };
  B: {
    refresh: string;
  };
};
```

The only thing we need now is for you to modify the `IIconSet`. To make this type more flexible I made the generic argument optional and added the [conditional type distribution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)(will show the result later).

After distributing we get the common part which is `info: string` and if the device type is in the `DeviceTypeMap` we get the part from it and intersect it with the common part:

```
type IIconSet<T extends DeviceType = DeviceType> = T extends T
  ? { info: string } & (T extends keyof DeviceTypeMap ? DeviceTypeMap[T] : {})
  : never;
```

Testing:

```
// type Result = {
//     info: string;
// } | ({
//     info: string;
// } & {
//     download: string;
//     refresh: string;
// }) | ({
//     info: string;
// } & {
//     refresh: string;
// })
type Result = IIconSet
```

We got the desired shape because we used the `conditional distribution`
Case 2:

```
// type Result = {
//     info: string;
// } & {
//     download: string;
//     refresh: string;
// }
type Result = IIconSet<'A'>
```

Usage:

```
export const icons: IIconSet<'default'> = { // no error
  info: 'svgString',
};

export const iconsA: IIconSet<'A'> = { // no error
  info: 'info',
  download: '',
  refresh: 'a',
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBuBLAxhAKuaBeKByAgrlAD54BCRpuAJhAGYCGArgDbC4DcAUF6JLAhTpMAWQZgoOAN5coUfAC4oMuXOoB7AO4A7FuobUlAZ2AAnRNoDm3VVFP17RgBbGzF67KgBfG1DJKVVXs6RxcoE3MrXx8uGN5MKABJROR1bQBlCGAAHjQoCAAPYAhtaiMBJFQMfhw4SuFIAD5JKDzC4tLytE8AfmUoCzp1V0jLbygAMigACjaikrKoAGsIEHU6CqFqiDEJPrqt0XEAbTQAXSgArwBKTyVtBAhTbi5CsHVTYChU7RMBn6MSmSP0yORo9GYbFwzWknkGwzwRnglnSbisuAANLEXm8Pl8AV8UGkjIokik0qDsgRoS1AvClLh4ZjPBodHoDAzmXJgqEGQxmTEgA)